# Does a two-sided expander remain an expander after removing vertices on one side?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, expander-graphs

Let $G=(L,R,E)$ be a bipartite *d*-regular $(\alpha, \varepsilon)$ 1-sided expander (from left to right), and let $\gamma \geq 1/d $ a constant. for every $v \in R$ let $r_v$ be an equivalence relation defined on $N(v)$. We then remove every $v \in R$ that has at least one equivalence class under $r_v$ that is of size at most $\gamma d$.

1. Does $G$ always remain connected? if not, what are the requirements on $\gamma$ so that is does?
2. Does $G$ (or its largest connected component, if it does not remain connected) remain an expander after this process?